# Dimmer switches have no ground wire

Tags: electrical, wiring, dimmer-switch, light

I went to replace two kitchen dimmer switches with new toggle dimmers (the old dimmers work, this is only cosmetic).  When I removed the face plate, I found the existing switches did not have a ground wire attached.

There does appear to be ground wires twisted together in the back of the box (see attached photo).

The previous owner remodeled the kitchen ~15 years ago, so I'm not sure if this install was just a quick carry over / install from the original switch install from the early 1980s.

Any info would be appreciated!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yep. The existing dimmers should have had ground connected.

Comment: This is just an information dump. You don't actually ask a question. What is it you want to know?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Add some ground pigtails

Take the existing bundle of bare (ground) wires, and add a couple pigtails of bare or green wire to the bundle, making sure the bundle is joined properly using a wirenut or push-in connector instead of just being twisted together.  The other ends of the pigtails simply land on the green ground screws of the new dimmers.

Comment: Simple enough! Thank you for the information.